# Can a virtualfield be based upon linked data in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

Is it possible for a virtualFields var to be the sum of a field from a linked table?

For example, in, say, an Invoice model, could you have

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'invoiceNett' => 'SUM(InvoiceLine.nett)'
);
```

but obviously only SUMming the lines that belong to that invoice?

Thanks.

== Using CakePHP 2.0

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I suppose this now boils down to 'should I?', rather than 'can I?'. That, as said, means it depends on each application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `afterFind` callback to get the sum. This avoids storing the calculated values​​, which should be avoided when possible.

```
function afterFind($results)
{
    foreach($results as &$result)
    {

        /*
        Use something like:

        $this->InvoiceLine->find('all', array('fields'     => array('SUM(InvoiceLine.nett) as total'), 
                                              'conditions' => array('invoice_id' => $result['Invoice']['id'])));
        */
    }
    unset($result);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with storing the calculated values?  IMO, it's a better way to go than having to do an extra query every time you want the data.

Comment: Storing a value that is calculated from other fields and values brings the risk of a desynchronisation between the calculated result and the computed values. What would happen if the database is modified from another script than your Cake app ? The `beforeSave` would not be called and the calculated value would then be wrong. If storing a computed value is really needed, it would be then better to use a trigger in the database itself to perform the calculation.

Comment: Seems like that highly depends on the application and the data that you're counting/adding.  But I see your point for some applications.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the best way to do that would be to have an actual `total` field, and update it anytime the data is saved (likely with a [afterSave callback method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#aftersave)).

So - anytime an `InvoiceLine` is saved, you run some code to update it's associated `Invoice` with a new total.

```
//InvoiceLine model
public function beforeSave() {
    //code to update Invoice's "total" field
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, yes, if that linked table is an associate that is joined (belongsTo and hasOne).

However this would be a poor idea because if you decide not to include that table you would generate a SQL error.

You'd be better off having a separate function grab the data or creating a virtual field that was a nested SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Defining your virtual field in the **respective Model** would make more sense.

If not done so, you will be breaking the MVC pattern.

You can use that virtual field from other related models.

If you don't want using them in all related models, you can always use the field
attribute whilst defining relations.

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'IwantVirtualField' => array(
        'className' => 'MyModel',
        ...
    )
);
```

In a model where you don't want virtual field
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'IwantVirtualField' => array(
            'className' => 'MyModel1',
            'fields' => array('MyModel1.id', 'MyModel1.name')
            ...
        )
    );